# How to serve a folder containing non-blade (Html) with laravel routes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I can serve html files and folders within the `public` folder in Laravel.

but I want to serve them as view & render them as view,

so I can use The **Authentication & Authorization middlewares** on them.

either if they were a lot of files, I don't want to write a lot of routes for each file.

Comment: @manjkiran appathurai : it doesnt, since it doesn't help me to not write hierarchical routes for hierarchical structure

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this would be to create static assets under the `resources/views`
like `resources/views/static`.

for example:

```
resources/views/static/foo.html
resources/views/static/bar/baz.html
```

after that I can place a **wild-card-like** route at my routes file,

then force view-engine to accept `html` exension, and convert url hierarchy like blade hierarchy

```php
Route::get('/pages/{url?}', function ($url) {
    View::addExtension('html', 'php');
    $viewPath = str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '.', pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_DIRNAME)) . '.'.pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    return View::make('static.'. $viewPath);
})->where('url', '(.*)');
```